# Is gridfit function good for making data grids?

Tags: matlab, grid

I have swath data in form of '.hdf' files of various variables, with which I have to make grid database.
My data has same number of latitude, longitude and data values like below

```
~~~~~~~
lat lon data1 data2 .... data125
x    x   x     x    .......  x
x    x   x     x    ........ x
~~~~~~~~
```

I have now copied part of my code here

Here, data1, 2... 125 is for data values for different height.
I am using 'gridfit' function for making a grid out of lat and lon value, and putting the data (data1) at appropriate positions in the grids.

Is there any other alternative of gridfit? griddata is not suitable for my application. How to check whether the gridded values are right or wrong?

Can anyone help?

Part of the code used:

```
[Attr_name,lat,lon,D1,D2] = data_read_cloudsat_ppt_col(dir(fullfile(files,'/*.hdf')));  %the data_read_cloudsat_ppt_col is a function to read the .hdf files
%% grid making from swaths
for hh=1:size(D1,2)
    x=lat;
    y=lon;
    z=D1(:,hh);
    cellsize=0.1;
    minx=min(x);
    maxx=max(x);
    miny=min(y);
    maxy=max(y);
    xi=(minx:cellsize:maxx);
    yi=(miny:cellsize:maxy);
    [X,Y]=meshgrid(xi,yi);
    [m,n]=size(X);
    ZI{hh} = gridfit(y',x',z,yi,xi);
    ZZZ_water=cat(3,ZI{:}); %concatenates the 2D files in 3D
    clear ZI
end
```

Comment: you should add the code in which you are using the gridfit function for any reasonable help

Comment: The code is too long. However, I can add some part of it.

Comment: the edit will come once it is peer reviewed. will take some time

Comment: Tryhard, in the future you can always click the [edit] link under your question to add the code yourself. @ammportal had suggested an edit but it needed approved before going live, which I just did but it needs more users to check first. (I think you also get notified of suggested edits to your own posts, so you could choose to approve/reject yourself.)

Comment: Yup, I tried to edit the question itself but it was not taking, so I had to copy it in answer. Now the question is ready, if anyone knows can you please help?